# How to merge these two css codes

Tags: css

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu . {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

How to merge these two CSS codes on the same code please? I want to add dropdown-submenu in the first code block.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't merging both of these just be this?

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu . {
    display: block;
  }
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: is work but i have the same problem a flicker in the mouse when i make it above the menu

Comment: and when i use just one code not facing any problem

Comment: @aminolok You never said anything about a flicker in the mouse...

Comment: How are these merged? you put them in the same media query but the two selectors are still seperate.

Comment: @Laif I thought amino lok just wanted the media queries combined.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
      display: block;
   }
}
```

Comment: dont think we can figure it out if we don't know your HTML structure

Answer (score 0):

Your original CSS is actually invalid, with a random dot at the end of the selector here:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu . {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

In that same line, I am unsure if you intended this to be the case, but the CSS will only apply to `.dropdown-menu` classes that are *children* of `.dropdown` when `.dropdown`

Removing the `.`, combining the two selectors would look like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: @aminolok You're not going to get a good answer if the only feedback you give is "not working bro." That's extremely unhelpful.